# How to use properly fit or fit_generator in Python in this case?

Tags: python, neural-network, cross-validation

While doing cross-validation:

```
from sklearn.model_selection 
import train_test_split X = X_train y = y_train X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.10, random_state=42) 
batches = gen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64) 
val_batches=gen.flow(X_val, y_val, batch_size=64)`
```

And here comes the problem:

```
history=model.fit_generator(generator=batches, steps_per_epoch=batches.n, epochs=3,                      validation_data=val_batches, validation_steps=val_batches.n)
    Epoch 1/3
    21/37800 \[..............................\] - ETA: 3:21 - loss: 0.2238 - accuracy: 0.9368
    /tmp/ipykernel_617/2842184565.py:1: UserWarning: `Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.
    history=model.fit_generator(generator=batches, steps_per_epoch=batches.n, epochs=3,
    37800/37800 \[==============================\] - 4s 96us/step - loss: 0.2662 - accuracy: 0.9265 - val_loss: 0.2950 - val_accuracy: 0.9195
```

But when I fixed:

```
history=model.fit(generator=batches, steps_per_epoch=batches.n, epochs=3,                  validation_data=val_batches, validation_steps=val_batches.n)

TypeError: Model.fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'generator'
```

I have already attempted some solutions I found in my search, but they haven't worked. Is there a way to resolve this issue and successfully train my model using the recommended approach?"

Comment: Presumably you just call fit without the generator keyword, i.e. `history=model.fit(batches, steps_per_epoch=batches.n, epochs=3,                  validation_data=val_batches, validation_steps=val_batches.n)`

Comment: Also note thius isn't an error (UserWarning: Model.fit_generator is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.) - it's a warning, your code should work but if in the future when you update sklearn to a newer version that no longer has the fit_generator method it will break